# (HTML) Text in image if scaled to mobile size (Skeleton Framework)

Tags: html, css, frameworks, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Im making my first portfolio website using the skeleton framework,

the website looks good on my screen (1920 1080) but if i try to scale it to a phone (nexus 5x) the text automatically goes into the image

Can someone explain it to me why the text goes into the image?

Here you have a screenshot of the problem:
https://gyazo.com/8f7be918817a9c3580fcae51b72442b4

If you want to check out the website online:

https://test.luukkenselaar.nl/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your html layout. Don't use `<img>` tag to set the image as background for division.
Instead try to set the image as css background of any `<div>` and change the min-height of `div` with media queries to make it responsive.

For example:

```
.target-division {
background: url('../img/some_img.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
min-height: 770px;
}
```

Change min-height according to your needs.
Also you can remove this code:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 30%;
}
```

This should eliminate your current problem.

Comment: For some reason if i change the background of the div nothing happens https://gyazo.com/6e78e449cc0147372c834e964a014925

Comment: @LuukKenselaar You need to wrap the background url inside quotes. Read my demo code above for the same.